# AMD driver installer not showing any text

Tags: graphic-drivers, proprietary

I was following [this](http://www.elementarynow.com/graphic-drivers-for-elementary-os/) link to install proprietary drivers for my AMD graphics card. As it says in the page, I downloaded the Catalyst Control Center from the AMD site and ran it. But the installer is missing any kind of text in it.

And it shows the following error:

```
(gksu:16410): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:16410): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:16410): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:16410): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(gksu:16410): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Here is a screen shot:

[image: screen shot]]

### Update

After seeing r3bl's answer I ran

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

which got rid of the theme engine errors. Also, I ran

```
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module
sudo apt-get install libcanberra-gtk-module:i386
```

which got rid of the canberra-gtk-module error.

But still the Catalyst Control Center UI is not showing any kind of text on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a little help from my friend I fixed this by:

1. Going to System Settings -> Languages & Region
2. And clicking on a popup there saying "The language pack isn't fully installed" or something similar, and installed it.
3. Then I applied it to login screen and all users using the button on the bottom of the screen.
4. Restart the system.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked AskUbuntu and found several different references that are pointing to this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-pixbuf
```

So, give it a try and let us know how it went!

([source 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304737/how-to-resolve-unable-to-locate-theme-engine-type-error-in-android-sdk-manager), [source 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106959/issues-with-quickly-tk-warning-unable-to-locate-theme-engine-in-module-path), [source 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66356/gdk-gtk-warnings-and-errors-from-the-command-line))

Comment: I've tried it, but unfortunately did not work for me.

Comment: This got rid of the first part of the error. But still the canberra-gtk-module seems to be missing. Obviously, I tried `sudo apt-get install canberra-gtk-module` but looks like the package doesn't exist.